# Clicking on Image Link with Selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, image, selenium, xpath

I have looked at the answers to similar questions and it seems like the code that I have should work but I get "Cannot click on element" error when the code invokes click on the web element.

Following is html markup segment

```
<div class="x-tree-node-item">
  <a title="Manage Users" class="sidenavmenu_unselected" id="m-22" onclick="toggleMenu('22', '');" href="#">
    <img title="" align="bottom" id="mi-22" alt="" src="ca/images/arrow.png" border="0">Manage Users
  </a>
  <div style="margin-left: 1em;">
    <ul class="submenu-show" id="mp-22" style="height: auto; display: none;">
      <li>
        ...
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Java code to locate the link is:

```
By xpath=By.xpath("//a[contains(@title,'Manage Users')]/img");
WebElement manageUsers = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(xpath));
manageUsers.click();
```

It finds the element but I get error:
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Cannot click on element

The ids are generated dynamically so we can't find by id and image source is used by multiple links. 
Thank you for your help.

*** Update ***
The problem was solved with help from JeffC and Xwris. JeffC's last comment showed that there are multiple nodes being found. So, I added following code:

```
       List<WebElement> manageUserImages=driver.findElements(xpath);
   for (WebElement manageUserImage:manageUserImages) {
       if (manageUserImage.isDisplayed()) {
           manageUserImage.click();   
       }
   }
```

Since there is only element displayed at one time with "Manage Users" as title, this finds the correct elements and delivers the desired results.

@JeffC, if you can post an answer with your comment, we can mark that answer as the correct answer. 
Thanks again to everyone who helped.

Comment: Please post the full error message in your question so that we can see all the details.

Comment: Let's do some debugging. Open this page in Chrome and open the devtools (press F12). In the console, type `$$("a[title='Manage users']")`. How many elements does that return? What about `$$("a[title='Manage users'] > img")`? If I were to guess, there are more than one element that is located and the first one (the one you are clicking) is not visible.

Comment: Another comment... you are waiting for presence of an element. This means it's in the DOM, not that it's visible or clickable. I would generally avoid waiting for presence except in specific situations. If you are going to click the element you waited for, wait for it to be clickable. If you are going to `.getText()` or `.sendKeys()` to it then wait for visibility of that element. Fix those bits, do some more testing, and come back and update the question with the results and we'll go from there.

Comment: For $$("a[title='Manage users']") result is <NodeList length="0"></NodeList> 
For other expression, the result is same.

Comment: This menu is dynamically generated by application. I do not have control on application. These divs appear after we click its parent menu item. The wait was added just to ensure that after the parent menu is clicked, we ensure that sub menu is displayed before trying to click.

Comment: However, $$("a[title='Manage Users']>img") gives a list of 3 nodes. I will look further to find out what is unique about the node that we are interested in. thanks

Comment: Sorry... I typo'd my CSS selectors and used a lowercase 'u' for 'users' when it should have been uppercase. It should be `$$("a[title='Manage Users']")` and `$$("a[title='Manage Users'] > img")`. That's why you found 0 with the first and you corrected the 2nd and found elements.

Answer (score 1):

It looks your xpath is wrong.
Personally I would start from the div and the drill down to the actual < a > tag.

In some cases where your web-element sits under a < li > tag, I would go even further up the tree and select a div which is not hidden.

i.e you instruct it to search for  under the specific < div >

Who told you you can select only by id? You can use anything! :)

This should work.

```
//div[@class='x-tree-node-item']//a[@title='Manage Users']
```

This should work as well. Correct usage of '*contains*' is as follows:

```
//div[@class='x-tree-node-item']//a[text()[contains(.,'Manage Users')]]
```

Hope this helps!

PS. notice that *text contains* is case-sensitive and will match partial text.
So if you searched for:

```
//a[text()[contains(.,'age User')]]
```

it will still be a successful match!

> Update after OP's comments:

You don't actually need xpath helper. You just hit F12 in your browser and then CTRL+f so you open a search field at the bottom. Please see my example on how I locate the title of your question with partial text match ('Image').

Also notice next to xpath where it says 1 of 1 (meaning that our element is unique). Try to do the same for your case. I suspect that you need to go higher up the tree and start from an earlier < div > so you can locate the rest.[image]

Comment: thanks, will try this xpath as well. Please review the comments on earlier answer. It seems like it is finding the image.

Comment: Seen them, that's logical if the http link is attached to an image itself. Grabbing the <a> tag will gurantee you are grabbing the actual http link you want to visit

Comment: tried all three suggestions above. Same error. However, the attributes are returning all blank.

Comment: Try to remember xPath as following:

//<name_of_element>[@name_of_attribute='value_of_attribute']

Another tip. In fact you can locate an element (if it is unique) without even specifying a value. So if the a tag is the only one inside your div in your example this should work as well:

//div[@class='x-tree-node-item']//a[@id]

Please notice how I'm not specifying a value for id (because you mentioned it is changing!). If there are no more < a > tags the above will locate the element as well..

Comment: I can see some <li> elements below, if there are some above this could be the case. If it is possible please share with us the page so you get a definite answer. Otherwise please attach more of the html code (upwards is where we are interested).

Alternatively I will highly recommend to install xpath helper for Chrome. This is a small add one which helps you try your xpaths.

When successful it will highlight the element so you are 100% sure.
If there are >1 matches for your xpath (so more element than 1) then xpath Helper will show this in brackets (3)--> 3 elements with the same xpath

Comment: try it out

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl?hl=en

Comment: Note: if you are able to locate your element using my xpath and xpathHelper for Chrome confirms it then you have some error in the way you are locating the element.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a locked down machine. Can't install anything on this one. However, after staring at the code for sometime, I see that the <img> tag is not closed in html. Shouldn't it have a /> or </img> before the </a> is closed?

Comment: Correct and correct. Both <a> and <img> should be closed with the respective tags as you mentioned. I can see the </a> tag but not the </img> - is it possible that all of this is generated dynamically on the go?

Key question is, are there any li elements on top of the div?
So is the //div[@class='x-tree-node-item'] enclosed into a <li> ?

Comment: Another question is, are you trying to click on 'Manage Users' so another submenu will show up?

Comment: Is this dynamically generated -- Yes. Will Manage users open another sub-menu -- Yes. Is the Div enclosed in <li> element -- No. There are bunch of <div> elements which constitute menu.

Comment: Okay thanks for your swift reply. Check my updated answer with the image and try going one div higher on each attempt. Best of luck! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156488/discussion-between-sohail-and-xwris-stoixeia).

Comment: @sohail If I hjelped you solve this, please upvote! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Leave off the "/img" part of your locator.  You want to click the anchor (a) not the image itself.

```
  By xpath=By.xpath("//a[contains(@title,'Manage Users')]");
   WebElement manageUsers = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
           .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(xpath));
   manageUsers.click();
```

Alternatively, the locator could be: `//a[@id='m-22']`

Comment: OP made it clear that id are randomly gerenrated --> so they are not the same on each run. You alternative method is fragile, I'm afraid.

Comment: I remember trying it without the image first, but I got similar error. Will try again. I added some print statements to confirm that it is finding the element. It does find the image and correctly prints the src value. However, on href value, it also prints the same src value. Do we need to do something with the img parent?

Comment: tried it without img and added print statements to print href, text and src attributes with following results
type:
src null
text

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?